# Check values in all previous rows in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following SQL table:

```
declare @t table(START_DATE datetime,INDEX_ID int, GROSS_SALES_PRICE decimal(10,2));
insert into @t values
 ('20150619',10000410,38)
,('20170311',10000410,26.49)
,('20170312',10000410,26.49)
,('20170317',10000410,38)
,('20170318',10000410,38)
,('20170321',10000410,38);
```

I would like to check if there are any temporary changes in `GROSS_SALES_PRICE`

For example, in this table I have a price `38`, then I have two rows with `26.49` and then `38` again. There can be any number of lower price rows so I think I have to check multiple previous rows?

I would like to make third column with value of `1` if this situation happened:

[image: Table 2]

Comment: which version of sql server?

Comment: How are your sorting your rows to identify the timeline of data changes?

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Comment: Rows are sorted with date column which i did not included. I'll edit the table.

Comment: What is your desired output?  I am assuming you will want this across multiple `INDEX_ID` values?  Do you want the `1` flag in just those rows that are a different price or a list of `INDEX_ID`s with a `Changed/Not Changed` flag?

Comment: Yes, i wat to do it with multiple INDEX_ID. I want 1 flag in rows where price is temporary lower.

Comment: How is the 'Price to return to after a temporary change' defined?  What if you had a row between your two `26.49` values that was `45`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> WITH maxPrice AS
> (
>     SELECT INDEX_ID, MAX(GROSS_SALES_PRICE) MaxPrice
>     FROM   @t
>     GROUP BY INDEX_ID
> )
> SELECT t.INDEX_ID, t.GROSS_SALES_PRICE,
>        CASE WHEN GROSS_SALES_PRICE < maxPrice.MaxPrice THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [CHANGED]
> FROM   @t t
> INNER JOIN maxPrice
> ON    maxPrice.INDEX_ID = t.INDEX_ID;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> INDEX_ID | GROSS_SALES_PRICE | CHANGED
> -------: | :---------------- | ------:
> 10000410 | 38.00             |       0
> 10000410 | 26.49             |       1
> 10000410 | 26.49             |       1
> 10000410 | 38.00             |       0
> 10000410 | 38.00             |       0
> 10000410 | 38.00             |       0
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=eb16e703188c4b85632b03ae4fa7ba5e)*

Comment: I am not sure this does what is asked.  It shows where a price has changed, but not where a price has changed *and then changed back* to what it was originally.

Comment: I don't think i will work. I have to check multiple rows because i want to check if tere are any preoids with temporary lower price.

Comment: Pelase, add your desired result, it's not clear to me.

Comment: I added the table with desired result.